# Stuck in checking if any of the two check boxes are selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My JS code can determine if any of the given HTML check box is selected and do further stuff.
But, I need to do some stuffs only when at least two of items are selected. a part of my current code:

```
    if ($('#a5').is(':checked') || $('#a6').is(':checked') 
|| $('#a7').is(':checked')|| $('#a8').is(':checked')) 
   {
    $('#circle_2').css('background-color', '#FF0');
   }
```

I can't figure it our how should I evaluate if at least 2 check boxes are selected. Any help on this please?

Comment: Show your HTML, then we can offer sensible answers instead of guesses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the checkboxes, filter out any that are not checked, and see if there are more than one left (two or more) :

```
if ( $('#a5, #a6, #a7, #a8').filter(':checked').length > 1 ) {

   // do stuff

}
```

Comment: Given the (lack of) information in the question so far, this is almost certainly the better way.

Comment: @DavidThomas - thanks, I often use the callbacks myself, but wasn't really sure what the question was, so answered with a regular condition ?

Comment: sorry guys, I should have provided with more information. However, this answer form @adeneo is the stuff I was looking for. Thank you very  much !

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest (assuming that the checkboxes have a common ancestor element):

```
$('#circle_2').css('background-color', function(){
    return $('#ancestorElementID input[type="radio"]:checked').length > 1 ? '#ff0' : '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this, in case you want to expand the functionality with some extra features.

http://jsfiddle.net/kasperoo/SharD/

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     var context = $('#form_container'),
         checkboxes = 0;

         context.find('.chbx').change(function () {
             $(this).is(':checked') ? checkboxes++ : checkboxes--;
             if (checkboxes > 1) {
                 context.find('p').text('You have selected ' + checkboxes + ' checkboxes.');
             } else {
                 context.find('p').text('');
             }
     });
 });
```